# Should Adam’s and Eve’s death be regarded as a sacrifice?

Tags: adam-and-eve, death, sacrifice

Should Adam’s and Eve’s death(loss of immortality) be regarded as a sacrifice?  In a similar way to Christ dying on the cross for our sins, I would assume Adam’s and Eve’s death contributes to their eternal after life.

> And the Lord God commanded the man, saying, Of every tree of the garden thou mayest freely eat: But of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, thou shalt not eat of it: for in the day that thou eatest thereof thou shalt surely die.

and Genisis 22 proves sacrifices among humans were something God ordered.

> Some time later God tested Abraham. He said to him, “Abraham!”
> “Here I am,” he replied.
> Then God said, “Take your son, your only son, whom you love—Isaac—and go to the region of Moriah. Sacrifice him there as a burnt offering on a mountain I will show you.”

Comment: @Geremia a sacrifice is an atonement for a sin.  I have assumed and still assume their death(no longer immortal) gets them into heaven.  Christ death may also be needed but it’s a fair point.  Maybe I should simplify the question would Adam’s and Eve’s death be regarded as a sacrifice?

Comment: @curiousdannii hmm I’m not so.  Is their death atonement for their sin?  They have lost immortality.  I have edited the question.

Comment: I think this is a better question to ask. Though it would be good to explain what got you thinking their deaths might be a sacrifice.

Comment: Why / how are they immortal? The general gist of immortality means you cannot die.

Comment: I’m not sure if this is a valid source but I read this https://www.catholic.com/qa/were-adam-and-eve-immortal

Comment: To suggest that _any_ human being, other then the single one who was prophesied, is a _sacrifice_ thoroughly contradicts scripture. Anyone attempting to offer human sacrifice within Israel was to be stoned to death, such is the abhorrent nature of such ideology or practice. There is but one sacrifice, that of Jesus Christ the Son of God, and this was pre-figured by exclusively _animal_ sacrifices under the old covenant.

Comment: @NigelJ I updated my question to include an example of 1

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Adam and Eve did not have "eternal life," as there is no Biblical evidence of that. They were in a temporary state which required God's testing before He granted them such life. The tree of Life shows this. Eating from that tree regularly only sustained their human life until the next eating. See Revelation 22:1-9.

Failing God's test, God pronounced judgement on Adam and Eve. One of the consequences of their action of disobedience was that God imposed mortality upon Adam and thus upon the entire human race which was in his loins figuratively speaking (see Romans 5:12-19).

So we see that Adam and Eve's deaths were the result of God's judgment, and had nothing to do with sacrifice. No person who does not adhere to God's Word deserves to live in His universe, so God imposed a death sentence upon the race until a suitable sacrifice could be made to fully redeem them. Death, then, is a temporary measure to curb sin. They were also banned from the tree of life to prevent them from living perpetually in their "fallen" state.

Adam and Eve, and all people, are saved only be believing God concerning the sacrifice of His Son Jesus Christ. note that God promised the Savior before He pronounced judgement upon the first couple.

Answer (score 0):

"Regarded as a sacrifice"-- to what end? Their death was punishment for their sin. Moreover, their sin brought death to all the world: "Therefore, just as through one man sin entered into the world, and death through sin, and so death spread to all men, because all sinned--" (Rom 5:12 NASB95)

There was, and is, nothing redemptive about the physical death of any man or woman, except Christ's.

Comment: https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2022&version=NIV

Comment: God didn't act to redeem humanity because of Abraham's obedience. Instead, he chose to redeem humanity through Abraham's lineage as a result of his obedience. God's plan for redemption was first revealed in Gen 3:15. Also, I might add that Isaac didn't die by Abraham's hand, so Isaac's actual death was not redemptive.